# php - split string by html tags fails

Tags: php, html, string, split, tags

I want to count html tags in a string. I attempt to do that like this:

```
$array = preg_split("<li>",$string);
$count=count($array);
echo $count;
```

Count is higher than it should be because this code splits the $string variable with the text "li" instead of the tag li.

How can I split the string with an html tag?

this is the string on which i try it.

```
Κυκλοφορητής Lowara Ecocirc XL, υψηλής απόδοσης για εγκαταστάσεις κεντρικής θέρμανσης με κινητήρες μονίμων μαγνητών, τεχνολογίας ECM, υγρού ρότορα.<br />
 <br /> Κατάλληλος για συστήματα ζεστού νερού χρήσης και θέρμανσης, συστήματα ψύξης και κλιματισμού, ηλιακά καθώς και για γεωθερμικά συστήματα. <ul> <li>
 Δυνατότητα ρύθμισης αναλογικής και σταθερής πίεσης, σταθερών στροφών και λειτουργία νυχτός.</li> <li>Σχεδιασμός υγρού ρότορα: Όλα τα περιστρεφόμενα μέρη λ
 ιπαίνονται από το αντλούμενο υγρό το οποίο ψύχει και τον κινητήρα.&nbsp;</li> <li>Χυτό θερμομονωτικό κέλυφος που κρατάει την θερμοκρασία του αντλούμενου υγρού
  (και του περιβάλλοντος) ακριβώς εκεί που πρέπει.</li> <li>Ρύθμιση και λειτουργία του νέου Ecocirc XL πολύ εύκολα μόνο με την χρήση τεσσάρων κουμπιών. Πρόσβαση
   στις προηγμένες ρυθμίσεις από PC, tablet ή smartphone μέσω ενσωματωμένου πρωτοκόλλου επικοινωνίας BUS ή Wi-Fi (προαιρετικό).</li> <li>Η ενσωματωμένη προστασία
    από εν ξηρώ λειτουργία σταματάει την αντλία και προστατεύει από βλάβες λόγω έλλειψης νερού.</li> <li>Τα ηλεκτρονικά μέρη είναι διαχωρισμένα από το υδραυλικό 
    μέρος της αντλίας για την αποφυγή προβλημάτων από συμπυκνώματα κατά την άντληση υγρών από συστήματα ψύξης.</li> <li>Δύο αναλογικές είσοδοι για σήματα 4-20mA 
    και 0-10V καθώς και επαφή για αισθητήριο &nbsp;θερμοκρασίας.</li> </ul> Συνοδεύεται από ρακόρ σύνδεσης.<br /> <br /> Ο κυκλοφορητής LOWARA Ecocirc XL καλύπτει
     πλήρως της οδηγία ErP η οποία θα ισχύει από το 2015.&nbsp;<br /> <br /> Έντυπα:<br /> <a href="http://www.lowara.com/lowdata/doc/EN/ecocircxl-td-en.pdf"
      style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;">Πλήρες τεχνικό εγχειρίδιο των κυκλοφορητών Lowara Ecocirc</a><br /> <a href="http://www.lowara.com/lowdata/doc/ml
      /ecocircxl-im-ml.pdf" style="line-height: 20.7999992370605px;">Οδηγίες χρήσης</a><br /> &nbsp;
```

ok..found the problem: the string was retrieved from a database in which tha character "<" was replaced with "& lt;" and ">" was replaced with "& gt;". When I used this code:

```
$array = preg_split("/&lt;li&gt;/",$description);
```

it worked as ti should.

I'm just left wondering why it was echoing the string with the characters "<,>" in their propper form instead of "& lt; , & gt;"

Comment: Why don't you just use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode)?

Comment: same results with explode too !

Comment: I think if you look at the source HTML, you'll see `&lt;`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the delimiters so, this should work:

(Also the count which you output is ever time 1 higher the then count of the tags because it counts the elements of the array, so you would just have to subtract 1 (e.g. `"<li>x1</li>x2"` -> 2))

```
$array = preg_split("/<li>/",$string);
$count = count($array);
echo $count;
```

For further information about regex delimiters and which one you can use see: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php

Comment: now count is 1. even though there are 8 li tags in the string

Comment: @user2484359 Then please post the string you use

Comment: i'll post it in the question because it's too long

Comment: @user2484359 Works fine for me! are you sure you copied my entire code! (See it working: http://ideone.com/1R6UKS)

Comment: The code was correct. I just figured out why it was happening. I posted it in the question. crazy !